# Entity Framework idle can cause delay?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using entity framework and API Get method on C#. I guess code is correct and architecture is correct too. But there is a problem:

When I request (via post man) first time API, the request takes about 3 seconds. I checked line by line in code and I discovered delay occurs when code goes to database (via entity framework).

If I request again the same API Get method or other Get Method before 5 minutes idle, the request takes about 300ms. If request after 5 minutes idle, the request takes about 3 seconds again.

It seems the entity framework clear its configuration and each query recreate configuration again.

API is correct! The query is correct because the next requests run in 300ms! The problem is Entity Framework! I guess problem is idle time!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's not Entity Framework but IIS.

A lot of people recommend to turn off idle timeout in your situation: https://serverfault.com/a/65897

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I am using azure. The IIS on Azure is set to "Always on". The delay continues. Can you help me?

Comment: Unfortunately @Leandro, besides pointing you at what is causing the issue, I'm not able to help you further. I'm not enough skilled in the IIS field.